# Custom accordion - using each

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to create a custom accordion for my page to that display my posts. I have it in list format using HTML and I am trying to create an effect when you click each header to expand to show more information.

But I don't want to have say six blocks of code for six of the `<li>` elements I have on the page.

Is there a way to run it through .each(); perhaps? Instead of creating each section? Try a more dynamic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at [this tutorial](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/expandable-collapsible-toggle-pane-jquery.html) ?

Because, as this [example illustrates](http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/exapandable-panel/), one does not need multiple conditions to achieve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".msg_body").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".msg_head").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(600);
  });
});
</script>
```

> All the element with the class name “msg_body” is collapsed when the page is loaded.
>
> The “slideToggle()” function of jQuery is used to expand and collapse the “div” with class “msg_body”.
>
> When user clicks on the element with the class “.msg_head”, then div with class “msg_body” next to it, gets toggled with sliding effect, making toggle panel using jQuery.

Comment: Oh, wow. This is much simpler than I thought it was. Let me try this out. So the next() is the main part that makes this work? So the .msg_head is the element you click to open the panel? Ryan

Comment: instead of hiding the class msg_body with javascript (jQuery)...use css (display:none)

Comment: Yes, msg_head is the class associated with each header. The associated function will toggle the visibility of each msg_body elements

Comment: On a side note, you should make this "answer" a comment to my answer. Answers should only be used for... actual answers ;)

Comment: The next() allow JQuery to access the next 'msg_body' element after the clicked 'msg_head', in order to toggle only the right 'msg_body'.

Answer (score 1):

Check this also pretty simple
Demo : http://demos.pankaj.pro/jquery-tutorial-guide-to-build-a-simple-accordion/

code
http://time2hack.com/2013/01/jquery-tutorial-guide-to-build-a-custom-and-simple-accordion.html